How to grab current user display information?
I'm looking for something similar to the output of following the powershell script:
Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController | Select SystemName, CurrentHorizontalResolution, CurrentVerticalResolution

Which outputs:
SystemName CurrentHorizontalResolution CurrentVerticalResolution
---------- --------------------------- -------------------------
PC_NAME    3840                      2160

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

In my humble opinion, .net 8 is server side framework but what you need to collect is client side information which I'm afraid is impossible. I think you might also don't want any application to get to know your client information, because if the app could collect your client display information, it shall be able to collect other information which bringing information leaking risk....In the mean time, why we need to collect client display information? For setting website width dynamically ?

you can use System.Management library
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace VideoControllerInfo
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           try
           {
               var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SystemName, CurrentHorizontalResolution, CurrentVerticalResolution FROM Win32_VideoController");

               foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("SystemName: {0}", queryObj["SystemName"]);
                   Console.WriteLine("CurrentHorizontalResolution: {0}", queryObj["CurrentHorizontalResolution"]);
                   Console.WriteLine("CurrentVerticalResolution: {0}", queryObj["CurrentVerticalResolution"]);
                   Console.WriteLine();
               }
           }
           catch (ManagementException e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying WMI: " + e.Message);
           }
       }
   }
  }

